# Producing a data response to a page using .done() in AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5.3

I am currently getting a response of 302 found when I process the AJAX. I understand I need to work with JSON in the controller but I am unable to get anything to even console log.

The AJAX is as follows:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});

          $.ajax({
              type        : type, 
              url         : url, 
              data        : data,
              dataType    : 'json'


            })
              .done(function(data) {              
                  console.log(data);         
              });     
    });

    i.submit();
  });
    });
```

**Network Repsonse**

[image]

Comment: what does the encode property do?

Comment: Would you say its not needed? I have taken it out and retried but with no changes to the outcome. @madalinivascu

Comment: 302 not found ??? are you sure that the status is not found ?

Comment: Error 302 means that you get a redirection. Headers with redirection url

Comment: @SteevePitis I have added the network response

Comment: Sorry mistyped meant found

Comment: And what is the response (still in the network panel) ?

Comment: I have removed any redirects in the controller and now the status is 200. There are still not responses in the network panel however.

"This request has no response data available." @SteevePitis

Comment: The javascript you posted is not valid, post all your code. Also `.done` is a callback for success `.fail` is for errors.